# Adding field values to a QComboBox in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I have a layer say 'Cities'. There is a column called 'NAME_1' in the layer. My GUI has a QComboBox in which i want the values of column 'NAME_1' alone to be displayed in the drop down of the combo box.

Can anyone help me in providing snippet in Python for getting a value from a particular column and displaying it in the combo box?

Comment: Next time, tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Sure next time it will be posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is no custom QGIS GUI widget for that (at least I couldn't find it), you could try something like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QComboBox

lyr = iface.activeLayer()
idx = lyr.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex( 'NAME_1' ) 
uv = lyr.dataProvider().uniqueValues( idx )
cb = QComboBox()
cb.addItems( uv )
```

Note that we are obtaining unique values of the field `NAME_1`, because I guess that's the desired behavior. Otherwise you would be showing your users a list with repeated values, which is not really ideal for a `QComboBox`.

Comment: Is it not the same as setting a layers Properties > Fields > Edit Widget to Unique Values?

Comment: @gcarrillo: The above snippet works fine for shapefile layer. When I tried with spatialite layer, it throws an error "QCombo.addItems(QStringList): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'. I am curious why this happens in spatialite layer.

Comment: @Jakob Not really, Ahamed wants to put a ComboBox in his plugin's dialog.

Comment: @AhamedFarook Cannot replicate the issue you mentioned. I tried on a SpatiaLite layer and still get unique values to populate the QComboBox. Did you change something in the code?

Comment: I havenot change anything in the code. But the same code still works fine for shapefile layer and gives an error for spatialite layer. Wondering how?

Comment: I did a Spatial Join alone other than that nothing was changed.

Comment: And without the Join, does the code work for other SpatiaLite layers?

Comment: Yeah Without join it works for spatialite Layers.